# It seems something ... vs something seems to be

Tags: differences, expression-choice

What’s the difference between it seems something ... and something seems to be (or any other verb)... ?

For example, This bottle seems to be very popular in Japan. Vs. It seems that this bottle is very popular in Japan.
Another example is, He seems to know what happened. Vs. It seems that he knows what happened.

For me, it is easier to make a sentence by using, “It seems that ...” than “something seems to ...”
Is there any specific situation where “something seems to ...” form is preferred?

Comment: They just have a slightly different tone.  "It seems" is microscopically more formal, but that's enough to make it arouse your curiosity more -- perk up your ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In language, when we find two structures in use it suggests that the users have preferred uses. So yes, to answer your last question first, there are situations where one form is preferred over another.

In language use, as opposed to examining sentences in a learning situation, context is key, as is whatever it is that has been said just before we want to say this sentence. For example:

- Are you here?
- Yes I am here.

So:

- Is this bottle popular?
- Yes this bottle seems popular.

And:

- I am looking for a popular bottle.
- It seems that this bottle is popular.

If you have a preference for a particular form then there is no reason why you should not use it, but the chances are that as your skills improve you will just use whatever form first comes to mind, without thinking.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and advice! It encouraged me to try to communicate in English more!